# How can I avoid execution of onTextChanged in Android's EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

How can I avoid that a code line like:

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.MyEditText)).setText("Hello");
```

Will cause an event here:

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.MyEditText)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
    int before, int count) {
// HERE
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
    int count, int after) {
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}
});
```

I want to know if there is any way to inhibit the execution of onTextChanged as I noticed in the case of selecting a AutoCompleteTextView's dropdown result (no onTextChanged is executed!).

I'm not seeking for workarounds like "if hello do nothing"...

Comment: Setting the text will trigger that listener. One simple way is to have a reference to the `TextWatcher`, remove the listener before setting the text(with `removeTextChangedListener(watcher)`), set the text, re enabled the listener(with `addTextChangedListener(watcher)`). You could have this in a method for convenience if you do it more than a few  times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How can I change the EditText text without triggering the Text Watcher I have on it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385081/android-how-can-i-change-the-edittext-text-without-triggering-the-text-watcher)

Comment: Example of same question solved for update on checkbox with listener http://stackoverflow.com/a/15523518/2162226

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Source for [AutoCompleteTextView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java#696) shows that they set a boolean to say the text is being replaced by the block completion

```
         mBlockCompletion = true;
         replaceText(convertSelectionToString(selectedItem));
         mBlockCompletion = false;
```

This is as good a way as any to achieve what you want to do. 
The [TextWatcher](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java#535) then checks to to see if the setText has come via a completion and returns out of the method

```
 void doBeforeTextChanged() {
     if (mBlockCompletion) return;
```

Adding and removing the TextWatcher will be more time consuming for the application

Comment: I tried editing this question but apparently the edit queue is full.
Long story short, if you're using an `AutoCompleteTextView` you can call `setText(CharSequence text, boolean filter)` and by passing the `filter` as `false`, you'll avoid triggering the `TextWatcher`.

Answer (score 15):

You can check which View has the focus currently to distinguish between user and program triggered events.

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if(myEditText.hasFocus()) {
            // is only executed if the EditText was directly changed by the user
        }
    }

    //...
});
```

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33151589/1788806) for a more detailled version of that answer.

Comment: Great solution do my problem didn't think of that.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you can simply use `mEditText.hasFocus()` to distinguish between Text that human-changed or program-changed, this works fine for me:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
    if (mEditText.hasFocus()) {
        // Do whatever
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I dont see how it helps

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way to achieve this would be to use `setOnKeyListener`.

This will only trigger when the user presses a key rather than whenever the EditText is changed by the user OR programmatically.

```
myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // beforeTextChanged
                break;      
            case KeyEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // afterTextChanged
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but will it catch a text change made by the user pasting text into the field?

Comment: Users tend to bypass the buttons and just click away or into a next cell.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an easy way to disable the listener, but you can get around it by either:

- Removing the `TextWatcher` before you set the text, and adding it back after.
- Or set a `boolean` flag before you set the text, which tells the `TextWatcher` to ignore it.

E.g.

```
boolean ignoreNextTextChange = true;
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.MyEditText)).setText("Hello");
```

And in your `TextWatcher`:

```
new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        /*
        If the flag is set to ignore the next text change,
        reset the flag, and return without doing anything.
        */
        if (ignoreNextTextChange) {
            ignoreNextTextChange = false;
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

It's a little hacky, but it should work :)

Comment: Will returning there prevent execution of before and after text changed too, or would you need another boolean check there?

Answer (score 0):

Only two ways I can see

- you check within the listener
- you add/remove the listener according to certain conditions

As the first way is a unwanted workaround for you I am a afraid you have work around with the second way.