# Android - programmatically change the state of a switch without triggering OnCheckChanged listener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, oncheckedchanged, android-switch

I'm looking for a method of programmatically changing the state of an Android Switch widget using `switch.setChecked(true);` without triggering `OnCheckedChangedlistener`. 
 My first thought was to swap it out for an `OnClickListener` but as this only registers clicks and you are able to not only click but also slide a Switch then it's not really fit for purpose as if the user was to slide the Switch from off to on then the Switch would actually do nothing as the user is not clicking...
If anyone's got a solution or a smart work around for this, that would be awesome

Comment: Please use below line of code.

"buttonView.isPressed()"

Comment: This is the true answer [Change the state of a switch without triggering OnCheckChanged listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73807933/1820553)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Well, just before doing things in code with the switch you could just unregister the Listener, then do whatever you need to, and again register the listener.

Comment: How would you go about unregistering the listener? sorry, i'm quite new to this

Comment: I think there are two options: 1. switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null); //not sure though, if that  could lead to problems...
2. create a dummy class, implementing the OnCheckedChangeListender with a dummy method onCheckedChanged, which does nothing. then registering a new object of that and later on again registering you default listener

Comment: so if I was to use switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null); how would I then re-register the listener? would it be switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);??

Comment: As long as 'listener' is a reference to your listener object, yes. That would have been my approach to work this around (though there my be better solutions).

Comment: hmm I can't seem to get the re-register to work... I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be putting in the brackets of switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener();

Comment: ah no worries, got it!

Comment: How did you re-register the listener?

Answer (score 66):

Set the listener to **null** before calling **setCheck()** function, and **enable** it after that, such as the following:

```
switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener (null);
switch.setChecked(true);
switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener (this);
```

**Reference**: [Change Checkbox value without triggering onCheckChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15523518/6292759)

Comment: Sorry but this didn't work out, onCheckedChanged was still repeatedly called.

Answer (score 47):

Every [CompoundButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton) (two states button - on/off) has a *pressed* state which is true **only when a user is pressing the view**.

Just add a check in your listener before starting the actual logic:

```
if(compoundButton.isPressed()) {
    // continue with your listener
}
```

That way, changing the checked value programmatically won't trigger the unwanted code.

From [@krisDrOid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52606437/10470378) answer.

Comment: This doesn't work reliably as `isPressed` will often be false for a swipe interaction with the switch, as opposed to a tap.

Answer (score 20):

I have one solution and its working fine at my end. 
I have added setOnTouchListener and setOnCheckedChangeListener on my switch control, and added following code to solve my problem.

```
    // set tag by default.
    mMySwitch.setTag("TAG");

    // Add OnCheckedChangeListener.
    mMySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (mMySwitch.getTag() != null) {
                 mMySwitch.setTag(null);
                 return;
                }

          // Do your stuff here.
        }
    });

    // Add Touch listener.
    mMySwitch.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mMySwitch.setTag(null);
            return false;
         }
    });
```

In this way setOnCheckedChangeListener is getting called only when check changed happens by human intervention by drag, by click, by touch.

Also don't forgot to add your valid string tag ( not null ) when your trying to change check status of switch control. 
like :

```
 mMySwitch.setTag("TAG");
 mMySwitch.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, helped me a lot!! no need of mListener, unfortunately there is no switch.getOnCheckedChangeListener() method. BTW: in your onCheckedChanged() it is possible to replace mMySwitch with buttonView

Answer (score 10):

Write a custom Switch or SwitchCompat and override the setOnCheckedListener.

```
public class SwitchCompat extends android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat {
private boolean mIgnoreCheckedChange = false;

public SwitchCompat(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SwitchCompat(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SwitchCompat(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}


@Override
public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(final OnCheckedChangeListener listener) {
    super.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (mIgnoreCheckedChange) {
                return;
            }
            listener.onCheckedChanged(buttonView, isChecked);
        }
    });
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked, boolean notify) {
    mIgnoreCheckedChange = !notify;
    setChecked(checked);
    mIgnoreCheckedChange = false;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

the best solution I can find is;

```
const val SWITCH_COMPAT_IGNORE_TAG = "SWITCH_COMPAT_IGNORE_TAG"

fun SwitchCompat.isCheckedWithIgnoreTag(isChecked: Boolean) {
    tag = SWITCH_COMPAT_IGNORE_TAG
    this.isChecked = isChecked
    tag = null
}

switchCompat.isCheckedWithIgnoreTag(true)

switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
    if (buttonView.tag != SWITCH_COMPAT_IGNORE_TAG) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers from @ronginat and @hyb1996 I made `SensibleSwitch` so that you can just drop it in your XML layouts, use the listener as you would expect to and not worry about it.

```
 import android.content.Context
 import android.util.AttributeSet
 import androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat

 class SensibleSwitch : SwitchCompat {
     constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
     constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
     constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

     override fun setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener: OnCheckedChangeListener?) {
         super.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, isChecked ->
             if (isPressed) {
                 listener?.onCheckedChanged(compoundButton, isChecked)
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener
{
    compoundButton, check
    if (switch.isPressed || switch.isSelected)
        if (check) {
            TODO("")
        } else { 
            TODO("")
        }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements all other answers.

Comment: he is literally asking "without triggering OnCheckedChangedlistener"

Answer (score -1):

Elaborating on Mahmoud's answer

```
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener switchListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    switchListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                //Implement on check change
            }
        }; 
      switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener (switchListener);

      //When you want to trigger the checked of switch do the following
      switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener (null);
      switch.setChecked(true);
      switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener (switchListener);
     }
```

`

Answer (score -1):

use this
`switch.setChecked(true); // first set value (from pref or server or anywhere) and than switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener (this);` add listener.

Answer (score -1):

If nothing worked here is a tricky solution.

Create a textview on top of the switch and add clickListener to textview.

```
 <TextView
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/switchLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/switch1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/switch1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/switch1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/switch1" />
```

Add elavation to textview.

Answer (score -1):

For the default switch writed `<Switch/>` on xml,
do this in kotlin to set it programmatically :

```kotlin
mySwitch.isChecked = true
```

Then, if you want to do some action when user click on it:

```kotlin
 mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, isChecked ->
            when (isChecked) {
                true -> { /* do something here*/ }
                false -> { /* do something here*/ }
            }
        }
```