# Change the state of a switch without triggering OnCheckChanged listener

Tags: android, android-switch

Is there any workaround helps me to programmatically change the state 
of Switch widget using `switch.setChecked(true);` without triggering `OnCheckedChangedlistener()`?

`switch.setChecked(true);` trigger `OnCheckedChangedlistener()` automatically but I need it triggered only when the user changes the state manually. So I need to stop
`switch.setChecked(true);` triggering `OnCheckedChangedlistener()`

Comment: you can use switch.setChecked(true/false) as you said

Comment: but it trigger `OnCheckedChangedlistener()` automatically which i need it triggered only when user change state manually

Comment: automatically triggering meaning?

Comment: When add this line `switch.setChecked(true/false)` to change state based on response from API and debug i found that, this code called                            @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(SwitchButton view, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            requestPermissions();
        }
    }

Answer (score 17):

Instead of using `onClickListener` to handle switch events you should use

```
 mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, isChecked ->
    if (compoundButton?.isPressed == true) 
        viewModel.onMySwitchChanged(isChecked)
}
```

the check `if (compoundButton?.isPressed == true)`
prevent running `viewModel.onMySwitchChanged` when you set the switch state like
`mySwitch.isChecked = true` or `mySwitch.isSelected = true`

Comment: not sure why this don't get more upvotes, this works and simplifies a lot of things!

Comment: This is the way to go and should be the correct answer!

Comment: agreed! This solution works best to me.

Answer (score 15):

I worked around this problem by using `setOnClickListener()` instead of `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`, then I can use `isChecked` inside the click listener to know whether the `Switch` is checked or not, e.g.:

```
switchView.setOnClickListener {
    val isChecked = switchView.isChecked

    // Do something with the check status
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind, that swiping the switch (instead of clicking) won't trigger this listener.

Comment: This solution help me too. setOnCheckedChangeListener() - works automatically even if you not click switch button. But switchView.setOnClickListener{} - works as it must be...

Comment: Does not work for swipe. So it isn't a good solution!

Answer (score 6):

You can remove that listener first and set it again after.

```
switch.setOnCheckChangedListener(null);
switch.setChecked(true);
switch.setOnCheckChangedListener(mOnCheckChangedListener);
```

Comment: I tried this solution but after set listener again it behave like user clicked switch and call `OnCheckChangedListener()`

Comment: well, you could try some workaround, `switch.post(() -> switch.setOnCheckChangedListener(mOnCheckChangedListener))`

Comment: Same behavior, it's really so weird  :(

Answer (score 2):

**2 ways**:

1. Whenever you change programmatically, maintain a boolean variable and set it to true. In OnCheckedChangeListener(), check if has come from the user or programmatically.
2. (Not recommended) Before you change programmatically, set yourSwtich.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null) to null. Then in next line again set your listener

Comment: 1- when i set the boolean variable in `OnCheckedChangeListener()` it will be always true even i changed it before `switch.setChecked(true/false)` as once it called `OnCheckedChangeListener()` it will be true                        2-  
I tried this solution but after set listener again it behave like user clicked switch and call `OnCheckChangedListener()`

Comment: For(1) first answer, you have to set that boolean variable as false always in OnCheckedChangeListener() at the end. And before changing programmatically you have to set it to true.