# Problems changing the status of a toggle button in Android

Tags: android, toggle, android-togglebutton

I have this toggle button in my Activity that indicates Open (if it's true) or Closed (if it's false). I implemented a setOnCheckedChangeListener method to change in my data base the status of the toggle button.

In this part of my code I change the status of the toggle button when someone clicks on it:

```
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(TabLayoutScreenActivity.this);
            alertDialog.setMessage("Have you updated today's menu?");
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                    callServiceToOpenBistro();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Bistro is now open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    OpenClose.setText("Open");
                    mySwitch.setChecked(true);
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please updated in order to open your Bistro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    OpenClose.setText("Closed");
                    mySwitch.setChecked(false);
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();


        } else {

            callServiceToOpenBistro();
            OpenClose.setText("Closed");

        }
    }
});
```

And in this part of my code I check in my database if the data regarding the toggle button stored in my database is true or false (Open or Closed):

```
private void callServiceToCheckStatus() {

    new VolleyHelper(this).get("current_status/" + PrefernceHelper.getString(this, Commons.Constants.USER_ID), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("bistro_status");
                String status = "",flag = "",opHours = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    status = jsonObject.getString("status");

                }
                if (status.equals("Online")){
                    OpenClose.setText("Open");
                    mySwitch.setChecked(true);

                } else if (status.equals("Offline")){
                    OpenClose.setText("Closed");
                    mySwitch.setChecked(false);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that in the callServiceToCheckStatus method, after getting the status in my database I change the toggle button to true (if it's already open) or to false (if it's stored Closed). But when I use "setChecked" it calls the "setOnCheckedChangeListener" method. And this is not what I really want.

Is there anyway to do this in a different way? Change the status of the toggle button without calling setOnCheckedChangeListener or to maybe use a listener that checks if the toggle was clicked instead of checking if its status changed (setOnCheckedChangeListener)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Checkbox value without triggering onCheckChanged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523157/change-checkbox-value-without-triggering-oncheckchanged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523157/change-checkbox-value-without-triggering-oncheckchanged) solution should works for you.

You remove the listener (`setOnCheckedChangeListener (null);`), call `mySwitch.setChecked(true or false)` and attach the listener again (`mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(reference of listener)`)

Comment: I didn't know I could do that. Thank you very much!