# using setText() don't want to call textwatcher events?

Tags: android, android-edittext, settext, android-textwatcher

i am using EditText. when i use setText(). TextWatcher Events are calling.
i don't need to call it? can anyone help me?

```
        txt_qty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
```

Thanks.

Comment: When want to call it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9385145/