# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (2 ... 2) ends beyond length 1

Tags: android

I got this exception, i am new for android so please help me.

> > E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (2 ... 2) ends beyond length 1

```
    holder.oldLaundriesQuantityEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if(s.toString().length()>0){
                int editedQuantity = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());

                if(editedQuantity==0){

                    finalHolder.oldLaundriesQuantityEditText.setText("1");

                }
                if(editedQuantity>oldLaundriesModelArrayList.get(position).getRemain_quantity()){

                    finalHolder.oldLaundriesQuantityEditText.setText(String.valueOf(
                            oldLaundriesModelArrayList.get(position).getRemain_quantity()
                    ));

                }

                finalHolder.oldLaundriesQuantityEditText.setSelection(count);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Is the exception occuring on this line? `finalHolder.oldLaundriesQuantityEditText.setSelection(count);`

Comment: yes i have exception on same line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue happens when you have already entered the text of length 2 say `"10"` but the remaining quantity returns a single digit one say `"9"`, in that case the count value will be 2. And on setting selection you are using count value and there is a string of length 1 only but setting to 2.

Instead of

```java
finalHolder.oldLaundriesQuantityEditText.setSelection(count);
```

use

```java
finalHolder.oldLaundriesQuantityEditText.setSelection(finalHolder.oldLaundriesQuantityEditText.getText().toString().trim().length());
```

For a better and cleaner one, store the value of

```java
String.valueOf(oldLaundriesModelArrayList.get(position).getRemain_quantity());
```

to a string before setting to the edittext and then use the same string object to get the length of the string.

Comment: code is working but on this screen the app not responding when i debug this than inside on "onTextChanged"  debugging continue for infinite ...plz tell how to solve this ?

Comment: So, when we change text inside a text change listener, I runs into infinite loop as discussed on this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385081/how-can-i-change-the-edittext-text-without-triggering-the-text-watcher So simply use a boolean flag to avoid the infinite loop

Comment: I have solved this kind of issue by this https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android/issues/27 answer.

Answer (score 1):

check size this oldLaundriesModelArrayList

```
if(oldLaundriesModelArrayList.size() > 0 && position <= oldLaundriesModelArrayList.size() ){
    finalHolder.oldLaundriesQuantityEditText.setText(String.valueOf(oldLaundriesModelArrayList.get(position).getRemain_quantity())); 
}
```

Comment: its not working and give java.lang.StackOverflowError: exception.