# persian number in edittext not work when i'm typing

Tags: android, android-edittext

i want when type number in edittext show persian or arabic number instead english number,**"its working well with method settext() but not work when i'm typing."**
i use this code for show persian number and for TextView and Button work well but not work in EditText in typing!

```
public class FormatHelper {

private static String[] persianNumbers = new String[]{"۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹"};

public static String toPersianNumber(String text) {
    if (text.isEmpty())
        return "";
    String out = "";
    int length = text.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
            out += persianNumbers[number];
        } else if (c == '٫') {
            out += '،';
        } else {
            out += c;
        }
    }
    return out;
  }
```

}

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

myEditText myEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_page);

    myEditText = findViewById(R.id.user_pnumber);

    myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            String s = FormatHelper.toPersianNumber(charSequence.toString());
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            myEditText.setText(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

}
```

i think must use `addTextChangedListener`

**UPDATE**
i get this error for force close app:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    java.lang.StackOverflowError
                                                                        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getTextRunAdvances(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1212)
                                                                        at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:2100)
                                                                        at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:2064)
                                                                        at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:969)
                                                                        at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:1178)
                                                                        at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:617)
                                                                        at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:480)
                                                                        at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:454)
                                                                        at android.text.Layout.getLineExtent(Layout.java:993)
                                                                        at android.text.Layout.getLineStartPos(Layout.java:519)
                                                                        at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:856)
                                                                        at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:827)
                                                                        at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:811)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.getFocusedRect(TextView.java:5834)
                                                                        at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:120)
                                                                        at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:94)
                                                                        at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:65)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:681)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
                                                                        at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:6547)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:6489)
                                                                        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1213)
                                                                        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.restartInput(InputMethodManager.java:1164)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4231)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4148)
                                                                        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:104)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4123)
                                                                        at LoginActivity$2.onTextChanged(LoginActivity.java:76)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8284)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4314)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4148)
                                                                        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:104)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4123)
```

Comment: You probably need [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Comment: i show output in Toast and Showed me persian number like number above '۱۳۶' in TextWatcher 'onTextChanged' method but setText() method gettting forced close app.

Comment: post the exception

Comment: @JohnJoe  i update question.

Comment: please post your latest code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code

ok you need global var like et_change

```
 private boolean et_change = false;
```

and in TextWatcher use it like below

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (et_change) {
                et_change = false;
                return;
            }
            et_change = true;


            String s = FormatHelper.toPersianNumber(charSequence.toString());
            myEditText.setText(s);
        }



        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

hope it helps you

Comment: thanks, it works. also works with 'removeTextChangedListener' and 'addTextChangedListener' methods. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385081/how-can-i-change-the-edittext-text-without-triggering-the-text-watcher#answer-34522587

Answer (score 1):

The exception comes because you are setting up the text inside the `onTextChanged` event. That triggers the event itself again, and this new event triggers it again ad infinitum.

I suggest you to use some kind of boolean condition to only trigger the event once.

Answer (score 0):

You just need using a Persian font that support "Persian numbers" for the view.
For example use shabnam_fd font as font family in styles.xml file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerIcon</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/shabnam_fd</item>
</style>
```

And add shabnam_fd.ttf font in font folder.