# How to capitalize letters in editText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

i have simple `Edittext` and when I'm going to change input letters in im setting listener `new textWatcher` and it's `onTextChanged()` method like:

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Log.d("qwer", "onTextChanged: " + s + " " + start + " " + before + " " + count);

            String originalText = s.toString();
            int originalTextLength = originalText.length();
            int currentSelection = textHeading.getSelectionStart();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            boolean hasChanged = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < originalTextLength; i++) {
                char currentChar = originalText.charAt(i);
                if (isAllowed(currentChar) && i < 21) {
                    sb.append(currentChar);
                } else {
                    hasChanged = true;
                    textHeading.setError("Please insert current letters");
                }
            }
            if (hasChanged) {
                String newText = sb.toString();
                textHeading.setText(capitalize(newText));
                textHeading.setSelection(currentSelection);
            }
        }
```

endless cycle begins when i'm setting validated data back to the edittext becouse it calls method `ontextCahnged()` again. so my goal is dynamically change input letters and i have to capitalize it. I know there is more the easiest way to do it. but i need to do by this way.

Comment: my goal is dynamically change input letters?? can you more elaborate it?

Comment: just set `android:inputType="textCapSentences"` in your EditText in xml.

Comment: when user types letters into the edittext i have to catch all input letters and validate them dynamically letter by letter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is with `TextWatcher` not with the logic what you are writing. Below Code block is causing the issue **(*`endless cycle begins when i'm setting validated data back to the edittext becouse it calls method ontextCahnged() again`*)**

```
if (hasChanged) {
    String newText = sb.toString();
    textHeading.setText(capitalize(newText)); // <<<<<< This line is culprit which is calling Watcher's method again and again.
    textHeading.setSelection(currentSelection);
}
```

To handle this issue, you need to do below steps

1. Remove Watcher from EditText
2. Set text
3. Add Watcher to EditText.

For more information read [How can I change the EditText text without triggering the Text Watcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385081/how-can-i-change-the-edittext-text-without-triggering-the-text-watcher)

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to do that:

1- Using common Utils

Library: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

```
StringUtils.capitalize(..)
```

2- By Custom method

```
public static String upperCaseFirst(String value) {

        // Convert String to char array.
        char[] array = value.toCharArray();
        // Modify first element in array.
        array[0] = Character.toUpperCase(array[0]);
        // Return string.
        return new String(array);
    }
```

3- From apache Common

Library: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

```
WordUtils.capitalize(java.lang.String)
```

Now you can assign that string to your input box.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the input type (of EditText) to  TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS.

**OR**

Set android:inputType="textCapSentences" on your EditText.

You can follow this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.AllCaps

Answer (score 0):

You can use following [InputFilter.AllCaps](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.AllCaps)

or this

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a flag ? I've modified your code by adding a `boolean setManually` flag.

```
boolean setManually = false;
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Log.d("qwer", "onTextChanged: " + s + " " + start + " " + before + " " + count);
            if (setManually) {
                 setManually = false;
                  return;
            }

            String originalText = s.toString();
            int originalTextLength = originalText.length();
            int currentSelection = textHeading.getSelectionStart();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            boolean hasChanged = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < originalTextLength; i++) {
                char currentChar = originalText.charAt(i);
                if (isAllowed(currentChar) && i < 21) {
                    sb.append(currentChar);
                } else {
                    hasChanged = true;
                    textHeading.setError("Please insert current letters");
                }
            }
            if (hasChanged) {
                String newText = sb.toString();
                 setManually = true;
                textHeading.setText(capitalize(newText));
                textHeading.setSelection(currentSelection);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use in XML

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

no need to write code for capitlize letter.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
  String originalText = s.toString().toUpperCase();
```

or

```
if (hasChanged) {
            String newText = sb.toString().toUpperCase();
            textHeading.setText(newText);
            textHeading.setSelection(currentSelection);
        }
```